# Way to change boolean labels?

Tags: android, boolean, label, battery

Is there a way to change the boolean labels? I mean, i'm making a control if the battery is charging via usb. If yes the output is true. I want change `true` in something else. Is it possible? This is the code:

```
public static boolean isPhonePluggedIn(Context context){
    boolean charging = false;

    final Intent batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int status = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean batteryCharge = status==BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;

    int chargePlug = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    if (batteryCharge) charging=true;
    if (usbCharge) charging=true;
    if (acCharge) charging=true; 

    return charging;
}
```

Comment: You want to change `true` to something.. WHAT???

Comment: This is very advanced programming, beyond most of us :). Serious answer - booleans are true or false, that's it. Maybe show what you are doing with `isPhonePluggedIn()` and we can help?

Comment: well what exactly i want to do is not print "true" but for example "is charging".

Comment: Then see Rapunzel's answer - although I would rather do something like `if (isPhonePluggedIn()) { print "is charging"} else {print "not charging"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about display text, you can do it as:

```
public static String isPhonePluggedIn(Context context){
    boolean charging = false;
    String result = "No";
    final Intent batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int status = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean batteryCharge = status==BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;

    int chargePlug = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    if (batteryCharge) charging=true;
    if (usbCharge) charging=true;
    if (acCharge) charging=true; 

    if(charging) result="Yes";  
    return result;
}
```

So you can set this String in textview or toast.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that this i'm inside an void method so i can't write the return.

Comment: @user2508402 The method is already returning boolean. Its not void

Comment: this part:  `int chargePlug = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    if (batteryCharge) charging=true;
    if (usbCharge) charging=true;
    if (acCharge) charging=true; 

    if(charging) result="Yes";` is inside a void method. I changed right now the code.